# External database questions for Android apps

Tags: android, database

One quick question on the steps to be followed while  using external db like mysql for android apps. I'm new to android dev and hence this question:

- Should I use sqlite to store values from app and then push it to external db every stipulated time or directly get the values pushed to external db when the user clicks on Save button?
- For a normal light weight DB, can I use mySQL installed on mac machine and then later port it to windows machine? will there be any issues when I change the OS where the server will be hosted?

It is important that the data should go to external db at the earliest, whenever a new record has to be added (eventually will be shared with other devices) Which is considered to be advantageous or industry standard or battery efficient.

Please share your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use MySQL with android, it is not ported to android environment, and even if it gets ported , it would be too stripped down for any advantage, if you are only using MySQL on server than it is accessed via an API from android and doesn't matter which database you are using.

MySQL is cross-platform and it doesn't matter which OS it is running on, same is true for postgresql and most of other database platforms so you can switch server side if you are not using any platform-specific feature
MySQL is not really a light-weight DB , it is feature packed, if you are just testing , you can use sqlite on you local machine also.

Accessing external DB would be via network connection , if it is important to get data there first then you don't have any choice , localstorage is fast , external storage is network intensive and normally depends on lots of external factors(internet connectivity, data speed), battery , there is no industry standart for this scenario , it depends on your requirement.

Comment: I was referring to having MYSQL on the remote server machine which will be mac laptop (connected to wifi) and the android device will access the data from this db via wi-fi. If local storage has to be used, I will stick with sqlite and use mysql as a server DB.

Comment: if you are only using for wifi , then how about storing it on server only and then synchronization from server, it would be simpler and you won't have to deal with synchronization edge cases

Comment: They caveat here is, the signal strength. It might not be strong all the time, it could range from average to zero in most of the places where the app is to be used. 
Also when you say "sync from server", does that mean each devices directly write into server DB and sync (or send) it to other devices? Am I getting it correct?

Comment: your question is not specific to android , it's more of a general synchronization problem, whatever you do there would be tradeoff associated , one example is cheddar app which only works online for any create update delete operation, you can do the same or do it like omnifocus, where there is a synchronization button which user manually starts apart from normal scheduled synchrnization, IMHO cheddar is much easier to implement and used by most of the apps, omnifocus method requires handling of edge cases from both server side and client side.

Comment: Thanks for the details, Vaibhav. Yeah now this has become out of android. I have few questions on the sync process too. Will write another thread for it.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you two options use it depend on you requirement.

first if your app is like web app. there is different users and they are use each others data and data can not effect to each other. like facebook, twitter

then you can push data directly to the server like [EXAMPLE](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2011/09/connecting-mysql-database-in-android.html).

second way :

if your app like [Example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.EMTPL.BarcodeStore&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLkVNVFBMLkJhcmNvZGVTdG9yZSJd)

in this app we have same barcodes and all number are used by different user like

there is 1,2,3,4,5 barcodes

user A use  barcode 1

user B use barcode 4

user C use barcode 5

then all three user's data save on same server and other two user get last updated numbers details from server automatically.

for this i used auto-synchronization. in this approach all data are saved into sqlite database and update on server in time interval 15 minute.

so it depends on your requirement what you want to do.

in sort you can use both way. there is no issues when you change the OS where the server will be hosted.

Comment: It's a native app and there could be chances where more than one user might be modifying the same data from DB, have to synchronize the data very frequently every 5 to 10 seconds, also looking to implement some sort of locking in DB so that multiple modifications at the same time is avoided.